# Entity Framework unremove

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to delete an entity if it has no dependencies. If it does, I am catching the exception and updating it as inactive. However, it still throws an exception. I am pretty sure this is because it is still marked as to be removed.

How do I solve that problem?

```
try
{
    _context.User.Remove(user);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
catch (DbUpdateException ex) when (ex.InnerException is SqlException && (ex.InnerException as SqlException).Number == 547)
{
    // Mark as inactive
    user.Inaktiv = true;
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); // <---- Throws same exception as above
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: The error is reproducible. I think it is pretty clear what issue I am having

Answer (score 2):

Solved it by resetting the change tracking:

```
// Reset tracking from deleted to unchanged
_context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
// Mark as inactive
user.Inaktiv = true;
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```